# Calculating relay-race times via a recurrence (in dynamic-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a database with a table of records storing timestamps between a series of interim-transactions and a completed transaction.

It's stored in a very odd way in the database, which is causing me problems.

Let's exemplify this as a relay-race. This is how the data's recorded.

```
RACE         TIME                             RUNNER    FINISHTIME
 1      2011-09-28 11:27:01.437        1                2011-09-28 17:19:00.843
 1      2011-09-28 12:35:33.427        2                2011-09-28 17:19:00.843
 1      2011-09-28 12:36:15.270        3                2011-09-28 17:19:00.843
```

The "Time"  indicates when the baton was passed and the last runner had finished.

So the math behind an individual runner's time is:
Time(Runner_n) = **Time(Runner_n+1) - Time (Runner_n)**

Except for the finishing runner, where there is no n+1 recorded. They get:
Time(Runner_final) = **FinishTime - Time(final)**

I was going to attempt making a new table and iterating through each race with a cursor-- to try and store tuples of: Race, RunnerID, TimeCompleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't require dynamic SQL at all, just a join.  Join to the next record.  If it exists, then you use the time from that record.  Otherwise, use the finish time for the race:

```
select t.race, t.runner, t.time as starttime,
       coalesce(tnext.time, t.finishtime) as endtime,
       DATEDIFF(sec, t.time, coalesce(tnext.time, t.finishtime)) as Seconds
from t left outer join
     t tnext
     on t.race = tnext.race and
        t.runner = tnext.runner - 1
```